# $content = $post->post_content; with formating

Tags: the-content, formatting, post-content

I'm trying to get formating but with no luck. My code looks like this

```
global $post;
$content = $post->post_content;
```

And to output here

```
<div class="tribe-events-single-event-description tribe-events-content">'.$content.'</div>
```

Please if anyone have suggestions let me know.

Comment: is this in a theme? Is there any reason why you can't use `the_content()` as normal between your opening and closing `div` tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i get your question correct, you want the post_content formatted like the content put out by the_content, right?

Change your upper code like this:

```
global $post;
$content = apply_filters('the_content',$post->post_content);
```

This does everything to your content that would be performed when outputting it by the_content();

If you only want the p and b tags, you can use `wpautop($post->post_content)` instead.

Comment: Thanks @kuchenundkakao apply_filters didn't work for some reason I have tried that before. But wpautop did!

Comment: Hm, weird...
If you want to have shortcode execution also, you can change the code to
wpautop(do_shortcodes($post->post_content))